# Connection to PgBouncer Admin Database

Tags: pgbouncer

I am trying to connect to the Pgbouncer Admin Database but I am little confused where the Admi user is stored.
Below my `pgbouncer.ini` configuration.

```
[databases]
alias_prod = host=abc.com.br port=5432 dbname=edf user=akl password=kji

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 5432
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
server_reset_query =
min_pool_size=20
pool_size=20
admin_users = FOO
```

Userlist.txt

```
"AAA" "XXXXX"
```

So to connect using python, I am using: 
postgresql+psycopg2://AAA:XXXXX@ip-1.2.3.4.5:5432/alias_prod

The `userlist.txt` has a list of users that I use to connect to PGBouncer. The alias_prod will have the connection string to the Production Database.

The list_port and list_addr are configuration setting for the PGBouncer.

Now I am trying to connect do PgBouncer Admin database using the command:

```
psql -p 5432 --dbname=pgbouncer -U AAA
```

But I getting:

```
psql: ERROR:  not allowed
```

I have already tried `FOO` admin_users configuration.

Any suggestion in how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `psql -h *Host address -U AAA -d pgbouncer -p 5432`

Comment: if you have any queries in connecting DB using PgBouncer. Please refer [this](https://medium.com/tensult/pgbouncer-routing-and-rewriting-for-postgresql-using-python-14b12d6595d).